# Weyl transformation of geodesic distance

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, differential-geometry

Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$ with a metric $g$. For two points $x,y \in M$ the geodesic distance $d(x,y)$ is defined in the usual way.

I would like to know if there is a formula expressing how $d(x,y)$ transforms under a Weyl transformation
$$
g(z) \mapsto e^{2 \sigma(z)} g(z).
$$
Is there such a formula for arbitrary dimension of $M$, or at least for dimension 2?

Comment: How is this a physics question?

Comment: I admit that the question contains only mathematical terms, but it arises from a problem in CFT -- namely, how does a 2-point correlator transform under a Weyl transformation.

Comment: For Riemannian manifolds, conformal changes of metric do not in general lead to good changes of the Levi-Civita connection: the geodesics can look very different indeed. So I don't see any reason why there should be good formulae in general.

Comment: Thanks Willie Wong! Do you think considering just infinitesimal transformations would help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to look at arbitrary Weyl transformations? If so, then the problem is hopeless as Willie Wong suggests. But If you're doing things related to CFTs, usually the only Weyl transformations which really matter are those induced by conformal maps. That's a much smaller class; arbitrary Weyl transformations form an infinite dimensional group isomorphic to $C^\infty(M)$, but for example on Minkowski space, the "conformal group" (in the standard physics terminology) is 15 dimensional, with a 10-dimensional Poincare subgroup which preserves the metric.

Comment: Thank you Logan! I indeed need to consider arbitrary Weyl transformations, not just the ones induced from conformal transformations.